# How to stringify char buffer for C macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

I have a `LOG(fmt, ...)` macro that does not work when using a `char buf[]` as `fmt`.

The code below is a complete (not actually) working example of the code. In `some_function()`, I am trying to use `LOG()` in two different ways but only the first approach works.

To solve the problem, I have tried using `#define LOG_STR(x) #x` in the following way:

1. To *stringify* what is received in the `#define LOG` by applying `LOG_STR()` to `format` like this: `LOG_STR(format)`; and
2. To apply `LOG_STR()` directly to the printing like this: `LOG(LOG_STR(fmt), 6)`.

Neither approach works and in fact I get segfault out of it.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define LOG(format, ...) do {                             \
                fprintf(stderr, "[LOG] " format " [%s]\n",    \
                        ##__VA_ARGS__, __func__);             \
            } while (0)

    static void some_function()
    {
        // This works
        LOG("This is a number: %d", 5);

        // This does not work
        const char fmt[] = "This is a number: %d";
        LOG(fmt, 6);
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        some_function();
        return 0;
    }
```

---

When I compile the code above I get the following error:

```
$ gcc -o log-macro-str log-macro-str.c
log-macro-str.c: In function ‘some_function’:
log-macro-str.c:15:6: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘fmt’
  LOG(fmt, 6);
      ^
log-macro-str.c:4:29: note: in definition of macro ‘LOG’
    fprintf(stderr, "[LOG] " format " [%s]\n",    \
                             ^~~~~~
```

I'd like to use `LOG()` in both ways as done in `some_function()` or without modifiers and just printing a string. I suspect I might have to stringify the `format` part but I can't seem to do it correctly.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stringify operator, `#` in a macro, converts preprocessor tokens to text in a string literal. It will not change the contents of a `char` buffer to a compile-time string literal.

To make your macro work, use multiple `fprintf` statements:

```
#define LOG(format, ...) do {                          \
            fprintf(stderr, "[LOG] ");                 \
            fprintf(stderr, format, __VA_ARGS__);      \
            fprintf(stderr, " [%s]\n", __func__);      \
        } while (0)
```

Comment: The important point is that the stringify operator and the string literal concatenation are compile-time operations while the char buffer is a runtime entity, hence this can't possibly work. You can't concatenate a string at compile time that is not yet known.

Comment: I was hoping to use a single `fprintf` but I now understand (from the answer and comment above) why this isn't possible.

Comment: @Daniel Well, it is *possible* to do with a single fprintf, but what you'd have to do to accomplish it would make it an ugly solution that I can't say that I'd recommend over this one.